# How to Use multiple User Providers in symfony 5. How to chain it?

Tags: symfony, security, yaml

UPADATED CODE and PROBLEM :

I use symfony Symfony 5.3.6.

I have two kinds of users: company & candidate.
I'd like to make them able to autenticate on their side. 2 forms are coming from front end. ( but for the moment no forms).

I use lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator to authenticate my both kind of users.
This is the first time I try to code for 2 providers in my security.yaml.
When I had only one , it worked. When i added company, it doesnt anymore.

Here is my updated code in my security.yaml :

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\Candidate:
        algorithm: auto
    App\Entity\Company:
        algorithm: auto


# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    app_candidate_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Candidate
            property: email

    app_compagny_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Company
            property: email
    app_users:
        chain:
            providers: ['app_candidate_provider', 'app_compagny_provider']

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: false
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        stateless: true
        anonymous: false
        provider: app_users
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    main:
        # anonymous: lazy
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/candidates, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/api/company, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Now, my message error is : "**Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "json_login" listener on "login" firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider..**"

i have followed this thread :
[Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "guard" listener on "x" firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574539/not-configuring-explicitly-the-provider-for-the-guard-listener-on-x-firewall)

By remplacing

```
api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: app_users
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

with

```
api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: 'app_candidate_provider'
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

But still doesnt work

Do you have an idea where i make a mistake ?

EDIT : the final answer told by @mcsky is the good one :

```
security:
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html
  enable_authenticator_manager: true
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
  password_hashers:
      Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
      App\Entity\Candidate:
          algorithm: auto
      App\Entity\Company:
          algorithm: auto


  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
      app_candidate_provider:
          entity:
              class: App\Entity\Candidate
              property: email

      app_compagny_provider:
          entity:
              class: App\Entity\Company
              property: email
      app_users:
          chain:
              providers: ['app_candidate_provider', 'app_compagny_provider']

  firewalls:
      dev:
          pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false
      
      login:
          pattern: ^/api/login
          stateless: true
          provider: app_users
          anonymous: false
          json_login:
              check_path: /api/login
              username_path: email
              password_path: password
              success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
              failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

      api:
          pattern: ^/api/
          stateless: true
          anonymous: false
          provider: app_users
          guard:
              authenticators:
                  - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

      main:
          # anonymous: lazy
          lazy: true
          provider: app_candidate_provider

          # activate different ways to authenticate
          # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

          # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
          # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
      # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

      - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/api/candidates, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
      - { path: ^/api/company, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: To achieve what? Is there anything not working? Are you facing any problem with [tag:yaml] itself?

Comment: When i had only "candidate" to autenticate it was working well.  But then i added company and now i have multiple error message such as "Unrecognized options "class, property" or " there is two much entity".  I have added the class "App\Entity\Company" as provider but it doesnt work

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you face any error, add the message

Comment: Also, please add more details about the Symfony version you are using. You've linked the documentation for version 4.0, but that is out of support since more than two years

Comment: You are missing an `entity` line just after `app_user_provider`, and I'm not that sure that you can specify two classes in one provider. But there's the [chain provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#chain-user-provider), add the two concrete providers (`candidate` and `company`) to it and use that as the provider in your firewall. The docs have a nice example (I've linked the current one, since `password_hashers` hint that you are on 5.3).

Comment: In your updated question, everything should be indented one additional level under `security:`. It might be an error when you pasted in here or an actual problem. If I follow your comments correctly and the current error is "Invalid entry under `security`", my suggestion doesn't make much sense, since there are other top-level keys before the providers. Can you clean up the question and update it to your current config and error?

Comment: I just updated it :)

Comment: There is a `providers` key before the two providers in the chain provider declaration, check my updated answer :)

Comment: thanks but i have a new error message that i have updated in the post. Still looking for the solution

Comment: The error message is clear, you must declare a userprovider for `login` firewall because you have many defined (before that you just had one, so Sf takes it). I added `provider: app_users` for login firewall, check the answer :)

Comment: thanks it works finally , you saved us. I know the message seems clear clear but when you never did it  and you mixe all the attempt because you are a rookie , you get confused.
thanks for you time and to not let us down :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't define one user provider with multiple classes as a configuration. It is not designed to work like this. Symfony executes this class `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider` under the wood, as you can see it work with `property` and `email` string only.

So I suggest you define two different user providers, one per class type.

So can you try this configuration?

```
providers:
    app_candidate_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Candidate
            property: email
    
    app_compagny_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Company
            property: email
    app_users:
        chain:
            providers: ['app_candidate_provider', 'app_compagny_provider']
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        provider: app_users
        anonymous: false
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        stateless: true
        anonymous: false
        provider: app_users
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Let me know if something isn't clear or don't work

Comment: Hi Mcsky. Thanks for your post. When i try this i have this error message -> Invalid type for path "security.firewalls.pattern". Expected "array", but got "string"

Comment: Did you forget the `api` node?

Comment: but I dont use API node . Only symfony to prepare endpoint on my swagger for Front. 
Now that i have made some changes I have "Invalid type for path "security.firewalls.api.provider". Expected "scalar", but got "array"

Comment: Symfony uses your `firewalls.api` firewall to authenticate each request made on your API. And I took the configuration from your post, so you use it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what did you change, and why?

Comment: I have followed Mcsky advice which bring  us to this new error message. I'm willing to let other learn but for the moment there is not so much to learn from it. As soon as i solve it i will explain the process

Comment: ohh I forgot one level in the yaml path, the `entity` is missing ^^' Answer updated

Comment: i still hav ethis error message :

Invalid type for path "security.firewalls.api.provider". Expected "scalar", but got "array".

Comment: I updated my answer to use the trick of chain providers suggested in your question by msg. It should do the job now

Comment: Actually I have tried this version since it's the model from the symfony documentation.
In that case , I have this error message :

Unrecognized options "app_candidate_provider, app_compagny_provider, app_users" under "security". Available options are "access_control", "access_decision_manager", "access_denied_url", "always_authenticate_before_granting", "enable_authenticator_manager", "encoders", "erase_credentials", "firewalls", "hide_user_not_found", "password_hashers", "providers", "role_hierarchy", "session_fixation_strategy".

Comment: It seems like a typo in yaml :) Could you update your question with your configuration at the moment please ?